# C# - Pass function to derive object property as argument

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I'd like to make this function more generic by specifying the property of Foo that I search on in the function arguments. At the moment I have to have a function for every property of Foo rather than just one generic function.

```
private Func<Foo, bool> ByName(bool _exclude, string[] _searchTerms)
{
    if (_exclude)
    {
        return x => !_searchTerms.Contains( x.Name.Replace(" ", "").ToLower() );
    }

    return x => _searchTerms.Contains( x.Name.Replace(" ", "").ToLower() );
}
```

Is it possible to make this function more generic to be able to pass the search property of Foo?

Comment: You could use reflection, but your application may become harder to debug and less performant. Also, are you sure you want to check whether a *search term* contains a *property value*, not the other way round?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have clarified.  I'm using the function as part of an entity framework query.  So something like `dbContext.Foos.Where( ByName(...) )` returns me the Foo's from the db

Comment: @Neil: I don't think that this works. `Queryable.Where` requires an `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` and not a `Func<TEntity, bool>`. The code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Annoyingly it does compile however throws an exception when it hits the database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily add a `Func<Foo, string>`:

```
private Func<Foo, bool> By(Func<Foo, string> property,
                           bool exclude, string[] searchTerms)
{
    if (exclude)
    {
        return x => !searchTerms.Contains( property(x).Replace(" ", "").ToLower() );
    }

    return x => searchTerms.Contains( property(x).Replace(" ", "").ToLower() );
}
```

You would call it like that:

```
By(x => x.Name, ...);
```

Please note that this method is not generic. It only supports properties of type `string`, because your search method uses `Replace` on the property and your `searchTerms` are also `strings`.

BTW: Please note the way I named the parameters. The .NET naming convention doesn't use underscores for parameters.