# C# and Entity Framework - Lambda function argument to derive object property as argument

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda

I'm trying to solve a problem similar to a previous question I've asked [C# - Pass function to derive object property as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438786/c-sharp-pass-function-to-derive-object-property-as-argument) but for working with entity framework

```
private IQueryable<Foo> Query(Query query)
{
    string[] searchTerms = query.CsvData.Replace(" ", "").ToLower().Split(',');

    switch (query.Type)
    {
        case QueryType.Name:
            return dbContext.Foos.Where(ByName(query.Exclude, searchTerms));

        case QueryType.Street:
            return dbContext.Foos.Where(ByStreet(query.Exclude, searchTerms));
    }
}
```

And I have the two following functions

```
private Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> ByName(bool _exclude, string[] _searchTerms)
{
    if (_exclude)
    {
        return x => !_searchTerms.Contains(x.Name.Replace(" ", "").ToLower());
    }

    return x => _searchTerms.Contains(x.Name.Replace(" ", "").ToLower());
}

private Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> ByStreet(bool _exclude, string[] _searchTerms)
{
    if (_exclude)
    {
        return x => !_searchTerms.Contains(x.Address.Street.Replace(" ", "").ToLower());
    }

    return x => _searchTerms.Contains(x.Address.Street.Replace(" ", "").ToLower());
}
```

Which works fine but there's lots of repeated code for all the different properties to search on.  I'd like to make this more generic by being able to pass in the property string to query generically.

The other question answers nicely for straight linq but I'd like to be able to achieve this in linq-to-sql

Would I have to build my own custom expression?

Comment: have you considered using specification pattern? http://blog.willbeattie.net/2011/02/specification-pattern-entity-framework.html

Comment: Do you have an example for dictionary? Or what I should replace with the dictionary?